# How to let a Vpyton object pauze within a simulation

Tags: vpython

I've been searching and reading quite a bit but I can't seem to find an answer to the question of how to pauze a Vpyton object in a simulation (for a second preferably). I considered briefly time.sleep() but this pauzes the entire simulation, my goal however is to pauze just one object.

If there are any question or I need to elaborate further, please ask.

Kind regards,
Zoë

Answer (score 1):

Use sleep(1), not time.sleep(1). However, I don't understand the meaning of "pause just one object". If by that you mean that you have several objects moving and you want to pause one of them while keeping the others moving, you would set a global variable t = clock() and in your animation loop keep checking whether clock()-t is still less than 1 (second) and, if so, avoid changing the "paused" object's position.

Comment: I'll comment that for VPython questions it's better to post to the VPython forum, where there are many more VPython users who will see your question than if you post to stackoverflow:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users